# QGIS remove number from the string doesn't work as expected

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression, address

I am fiddling with addresses, where I would like to remove the street number.

So far I found some solutions leading to explain how to get rid of the numbers but from the right side of the string:

[Extract left part of field with regexp_substr after two specific charaters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411296/extract-left-part-of-field-with-regexp-substr-after-two-specific-charaters)
[Removing string to the right of a character using QGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240812/removing-string-to-the-right-of-a-character-using-qgis-field-calculator)
[How to split string, removing digits keeping letters/words](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258276/how-to-split-string-removing-digits-keeping-letters-words)

as well as some options with replacing the parts of the string:

[Replacing characters using an expression in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382905/replacing-characters-using-an-expression-in-qgis)
[How to extract part of string after '*', '~', '-' or '#'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198610/how-to-extract-part-of-string-after-or)
[Replace using regular expression?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318073/replace-using-regular-expression)

but I couldn't find either how to remove the number from the end of the string nor what is the definition of any number in QHIS expressions:

https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html

I used these 2 codes but both didn't work as expected:

```
  right ( "Address L1", length("Address L1")-regexp_match("Address L1" ,'(_S\\d+)')-2)

  substr("Address L1",regexp_match("Address L1",'')+2)
```

because they take down just the first 2 characters some addresses are fine, other ones have additional space at the very beginning and others still keep some numbers. I need something, which would allow me to remove the stuff before the first space. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Correction: You want to remove the part before the first space, if that part consists of numbers. Otherwise you'd end up with `facility` instead of `recycling facility`. You know how to check for numbers, so use this as your condition, and then `regexp_match()` for spaces if there are numbers in the address.

Comment: Yes, I want to get rid of everything before the first space. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove the numbers at the beginning of the string and its optional following space, you can use

```
regexp_replace(address,'^\\d*\\s?','')
```

`^`: beginning of the string
`\\d`: followed by any digit
`*`: found 0 or more time
`\\s`: followed by a space
`?`: found 0 or 1 time

Comment: Love the breakdown of the reg exp. Maybe I can remember it this time.

Comment: Yes, so do I! It's a good way to understand it. @JGH how can we follow it by the second, third space, etc?